# Reading From Text File and Save to List

Tags: c++

Im trying to read from a file called `stock.txt`, which contains the following values:

**ID, Item, Colour, Size, Quantity, Price**

```
11,T-shirt,blue,XL,2,10.500000
12,Supreme,red,M,10,20.500000
13,BANG,red,M,10,20.500000
```

I wanted to store each item in a vector list, how can I do that?

```
int main() {
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("Stock.txt");

        string id; string title; string colour; string size; string quantity; string cost;

        //If file open is successful
        while(infile.good()){
            getline(infile,id,',');
            getline(infile,title,',');
            getline(infile,colour,',');
            getline(infile,size,',');
            getline(infile,quantity,',');
            getline(infile,cost,'\n');        
        }

        infile.close();
}
```

The goal is then to implement a search function where I could search for specific item from that list (for example by using ID, or title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common ways to add elements to an `std::vector`. One is with `.push_back()` and the other is `.emplace_back()`. `push_back()` will construct the object, then copy it into the vector. `emplace_back()` will construct the object directly in the container.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by

> I wanted to store each item in a vector list

but I'll show you a few different ways.

## A Vector of Strings

Since it looks like you have everything as an `std::string`, you could go ahead and just make a vector of strings. However, you have many numerical values that really shouldn't be strings. In the sections following, I'll give some strategies for being able to maintain these values as numerical.

However, here, if you wanted every entry to have its own element in the vector, your code would become

```cpp
int main() 
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("Stock.txt");

    string id, title, color, size, quantity, cost;
    vector<string> all_data;  // Create vector

    //If file open is successful
    while(getline(infile, id, ','))
    {
        getline(infile, title,    ',');
        getline(infile, color,    ',');
        getline(infile, size,     ',');
        getline(infile, quantity, ',');
        getline(infile, cost,    '\n');

        // Add to vector
        all_data.push_back(title);
        all_data.push_back(color);
        all_data.push_back(size);
        all_data.push_back(quantity);
        all_data.push_back(cost);
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

Note that I did change some of your original code.

If you wanted to do one big string as an element, you can do that too:

```cpp
int main() 
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("Stock.txt");

    string id, title, color, size, quantity, cost;
    vector<string> all_data;  // Create vector

    //If file open is successful
    while(getline(infile, id, ','))
    {
        getline(infile, title,    ',');
        getline(infile, color,    ',');
        getline(infile, size,     ',');
        getline(infile, quantity, ',');
        getline(infile, cost,    '\n');

        // Make one big string
        string new_element = 
            title + ' ' + color + ' ' + ' ' + size + ' ' +
            quantity + ' ' + cost;
        
        // Add the new element to the vector
        all_data.push_back(new_element);  
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

## A Vector of Structs

Possibly the best way to go here to preserve the original datatypes. With this approach, declare your data as a struct and then feed everything in that way.

```cpp
struct Data
{
    int id;
    string title, color, size;
    unsigned quantity;
    double cost;
};

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("Stock.txt");

    string id, title, color, size, quantity, cost;
    vector<Data> all_data; // Create vector of Data

    //If file open is successful
    while (infile.peek() != EOF)
    {
        int      new_id;
        unsigned new_quantity;
        double   new_cost;

        getline(infile, id, ',');
        getline(infile, title, ',');
        getline(infile, color, ',');
        getline(infile, size, ',');
        getline(infile, quantity, ',');
        getline(infile, cost, '\n');

        // Convert some datatypes
        new_id = stoi(id);
        new_quantity = static_cast<unsigned>(stol(quantity));
        new_cost = stod(cost);

        // Add new element to vector
        all_data.emplace_back(Data{ new_id, title, color, size, new_quantity, new_cost });
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

Let me know if there's anything I can clear up.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I got a question rgearding the variable type, so in my case I have ID (int), quantiy(int) and cost (float), I cant do this with `getline` it seems

Comment: @user11453590 So it's important to understand what's happening in the SECOND example (that's the one you'll want to look at). Everything is being read in as a string, then _some_ of those strings are being converted to numeric types (where it says "`convert some datatypes`"). The `new_id` (etc.) variables inside the loop are used to hold the _numerical_ values while the variables outside the loop are still all strings. Does that help at all?

Comment: Yes I do now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Create some synergy between your data structure and your code:

```
struct stock_item
{
    std::string id;
    std::string title;
    std::string colour;
    std::string size;
    int quantity;
    double cost;
};
```

Once you're able to create a `stock_item` from a line in your file, you can easily store and manipulate it wherever/however you want:

```
std::vector<stock_item> some_vector;
stock_item some_stock_item;
// ...
some_vector.push_back(some_stock_item);
// ...
for (auto const& item : some_vector) {
    std::cout << "Item #" << item.id << '\n';
}
```

So you need to parse that file:

```
auto stocks_from_stream(std::istream& in)
{
    std::vector<stock_item> result;
    std::string stock_line;
    while(std::getline(in, stock_line)) {
        auto item = stock_from_string(stock_line);
        result.push_back(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You then need to define this `stock_from_string` function:

```
auto stock_from_string(std::string const& line)
{
    stock_item result;
    // parse your line here
    return result;
}
```

And voilà!